# Programming Power BI datasets with the Tabular Object Model

Tags: c#, powerbi, azure-functions, ssas, ssas-tabular

I try to build Azure Function that getting some data from Power BI dataset,
I do it according to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tom/tom-pbi-datasets?view=sql-analysis-services-2022

I got error : Exception: Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ConnectionException: The connection string is not valid. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

I tried several thing without success.
I have app registration that have full access to workspace and can perform actions by REST API, and the workspace is PPU workspace, so the XMLA endpoint is enabled and all permissions defined.

I tried several connection strings I will list all of them

What should be a connection string or I'm missing something else?

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular;
using System;
using RestSharp;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace GetRLSDetails
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        [Obsolete]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            
            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");            
            string datasetname = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("datasetname");
            string tenantId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("tenantId");
            string appId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("appId");
            string appSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("appSecret");
            string workspaceConnection = $"powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/{tenantId}/BI Management TEST";
Server server = new Server();

//first version
string connectStringUser = $"Provider = MSOLAP;Data source = {workspaceConnection};initial catalog={datasetname};User ID=app:{appId};Password={appSecret};";
//second version
string connectStringUser = $"Provider = MSOLAP;Data Source ={workspaceConnection};Initial Catalog ={datasetname};User ID =app:{appId}@{tenantId}; Password ={appSecret}; Persist Security Info = True; Impersonation Level = Impersonate";
//third version
 string connectStringUser = $"Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source={workspaceConnection};User ID=app:{appId}@{tenantId};Password={appSecret};";
//fourth version
string connectStringUser = $"Data Source={workspaceConnection};User ID=app:{appId}@{tenantId};Password={appSecret};";
//using PBI  access token 
string connectStringUser = $"Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source={workspaceConnection};UserID=;Password={accessToken};";

server.Connect(connectStringUser);
            string response_text = "";
            foreach (Database database in server.Databases)
            {
                response_text= response_text+database.Name+',';
            }
            response.WriteString(response_text);
            return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what you are using for `tenantId` here.

```
string workspaceConnection = $"powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/{tenantId}/BI Management TEST";
```

In most cases this should be `myorg`, not anything specific, so I'm not sure why you have a variable there. You can check the entire address in Power BI following the [instructions from your link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tom/tom-pbi-datasets?view=sql-analysis-services-2022#getting-started-with-the-tabular-object-model).

If that's not it, I would connect to my Power BI dataset from Excel to build a Connection string that works.

In Excel, select **Insert > PivotTable > From Power BI** then pick your model. Once you've connected, you can get the connection string from **Data > Queries & Connections** then click on **Connections** in the Queries & Connections pane, then right click your connection and select **Properties...** then switch to the **Definitions** tab:

[image: Excel Connection]

Just copy the connection string from here, or maybe it will help you see what's off in what you are trying.

Comment: Thank you, finally it worked! But I must use user credential and not service credential.